# Redshift - Restrict Access on Referenced object used in a view definition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, access-control

I am facing an issue in implementing access controls in redshift.

I have  2 schemas:

1. **etl_load** schema where **customer** table is created
2. **analytics_view** schema where view **v_cust** referencing **etl_load.customer** is created.

I have created a user group **analytics_user** and granted *read only access* to **analytics_view** schema to execute select statements on **v_cust** view without giving any sort of access on etl_load schema.

One of the user from **analytics_user group** is trying to execute select statement on **v_cust** and getting error:

`permission is denied for schema "etl_load", which is not in schema list in order form. You need to have access on schema "etl_load" also, as it must be getting referenced in the object from where you are trying to select`

How can be grant access to users from **analytics_user** group to access objects in **analytics_view** schema without granting them access to query *referenced objects* in **etl_load** schema directly?

Thanks in advance!